# pdo fetchAll function returns an empty array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i know it might be a duplicate question but i really didn't find any help reading other replies that's why i decided to post my issue i'm trying to pull out some data using pdo with prepared statement but i always get an empty array even though my query seems to be ok here is my code any help would be appreciated .

```
$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'dbname';
$password = 'xxxxx';
$user = 'xxxxx';
try{

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname:$dbname",$user,$password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM subregions");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($result);
/*foreach($result as $row){
    echo "<li>$row['name']</li>";
}*/
}catch (PDOexception $e){
  $e->getMessage();
  die();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, it should work.

```
<?php
/* Connect to an ODBC database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test;';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM email_table");
    $sth->execute();
    echo $sth->rowcount();
    $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($result);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Thanks
Amit

Comment: @mark-wallest,  in the code mentioned above please replace your table name and replace the database name,

Comment: what is not working  here, can you please add comment.

Comment: Thanks I've noticed that : i replaced it with = and it works fine

Comment: @Markwallest the please vote the correct answer, it will be helpful for the people who will be referring to your question and answer. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The answer is simple. If empty array is returned, that means your query returned no rows. That's logic.